# Eclipse: how to make java folders to display as a tree?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Why folders in packages are still displayed as a separate item (not nested, with exception of folder `1`), but in folder explorer they are nested:

[image]

How to make them display as nested items?

Comment: click on the little arrow pointing downwards(`view menu`) where the package explorer is. chose the option `package presentation` and chose `hierarchical` there.

Comment: @KevinEsche, that is right, thanks! you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the way to convert flat folder structure to heirarchical.

[image]